# Android: Load url on other activity's WebView

Tags: android, view, android-activity, webview

As the title says.

For example:
I have MainActivity and main.xml
main.xml has WebView "@+id/WebView1".

After opening SecondActivity, I want it to load an URL on the MainActivity's webview.

Any solutions?

Comment: Implement custom Listeners(interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your MainActivity.java

```
WebView webView;
static WebView sWebView; // because we will use in static method
```

put them in oncreate method;

```
webView = (WebView )findViewById(webview);
sWebView= webView ;
```

create the method below

```
    // it is static because we will call it from second actvity 
    static loadUrl (String Url){
       sWebView.webloadUrl(url);
    }
```

in the second activiy on create method,

```
MainActivity.loadUrl("your URL"); // because load url is a statci method, you can call the it from other class.
```

Comment: OK, the WebView is found, and loads the URL succesfully. But the onCreate of the SecondActivity still opens a new window (erasing super.onCreate() will give an error)

Comment: Lol, you're funny :P But you're good too. I solved it myself by doing this.finish() after opening the requested URL. Everything is working great now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put your url in extras.

```
myIntet.putExtra("url", "www.abc.com");
```

access it in second activity.

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
```

render the url in webview.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: the "findViewById(R.id.WebView1);" is giving a null.

Comment: At which point of application lifecycle are you trying to do it?

Comment: you should try this in the onCreate method of activity.